# What are the other options for storing data?

Tags: mobile, java-me, midp, rms

I noticed that `recordstores` take much `memory` when their number reach more than 8. This makes impossible `image` creation inside device and `camera` capturing. Although my application needs to record more than 8 "table" data. So what are the other possibilities to record persistently data ?

Comment: did you consider FileConnection API ([JSR 75](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsr75/info "'jsr75' tag wiki"))?

Comment: Is it persistent ? That is : are data always available even if device is turned off ?

Comment: sure - it is as persistent as any file you use at your regular PC. "File" part in `FileConnection` is to denote just this :)

Comment: But there is security issue with it : what if end-user deletes the file ?

Comment: sure, and the thing to keep in mind here is that hundreds thousands perfectly working desktop applications somehow manage to handle exactly this kind "issues" don't they? Desktop apps use files alot - you can just learn how it's done by these

Comment: what is your targeted phone ??

Comment: I am developping a `J2ME` project , it is a project to be sold by our company. So the application will be installed to any kind of mobile device ! The testing-device I use is Alcatel OT-806D .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app in memory card then the record store takes the space in memory card.

Otherwise better you create a file and store the data in that file using "FileConnection" API.

Comment: I need the reason for down voting my answer.Due to correcting myself.So i cannot repeat my mistakes.I understand that i had some mistakes.Knowing the reason helps me to correct my self.Dont mistakes me others please.